# Selenium find element by class name doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I just started learning selenium so when I tried do get something from https://www.python.org/ with find_element_by_class_name("small-widget get-started-widget") it didn't work even though there is a class name named that. My code is below.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.python.org/")
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("small-widget get-started-widget")
print(element.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

I get an error saying "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".small-widget get-started-widget"}" Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `small-widget get-started-widget` is two names use only one `small-widget` or `get-started-widget`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The element with this class name does not exist, so the class name is wrong. I think because of the whitespace at the class name.
Try this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("small-widget.get-started-widget")
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. So I have to replace all the whitespace with  a "." correct?