# Python Selenium find element by class name not working and there is an unconditional dot at 0 position of name string in the raised error

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Slider element looks like `span id="nc_2_n1z" class="nc_iconfont btn_slide"` in devtools (chrome f12)

Works fine:

```
e_slider = driver.find_element(By.ID, "nc_2_n1z")
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop_by_offset(e_slider, 301, 0).perform()
```

Doesnt work:

```
e_slider = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "nc_iconfont btn_slide")
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop_by_offset(e_slider, 301, 0).perform()
```

And raises error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":".nc_iconfont btn_slide"}

**The problem is a 'space' at class name.**
Instead of `"nc_iconfont btn_slide"` you gotta use `"nc_iconfont.btn_slide"`
Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/65257415/14508423

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium find element by class name doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65257367/selenium-find-element-by-class-name-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 2):

`nc_iconfont btn_slide` are actually 2 class names: `nc_iconfont` and `btn_slide` while `find_element(By.CLASS_NAME)` method can receive a single class name only.
To locate element by multiple class names you can use XPATH or CSS_SELECTOR.
So instead of

```
e_slider = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "nc_iconfont btn_slide")
```

You can use

```
e_slider = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".nc_iconfont.btn_slide")
```

or

```
e_slider = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class,'nc_iconfont btn_slide']")
```

Comment: I mean replacing space with a dot `Instead of "nc_iconfont btn_slide" you gotta use "nc_iconfont.btn_slide"` is enough for it to work.

Comment: If so where is a question?